# Rails 4 - model array relationship between 2 object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

To learn rails, I am building an application to select protect type using dynamic questionnaire. I have 2 objects "Project type" and "Questions". For each project type I now need to set whether or not a question is applicable.

**Now my question how to model this?**

1. With a column with data type array on the project type object - yet it has unknown number of fields (i.e. Questions) that need to be Boolean
2. Other option

It will also need a form part that reads the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution - need new object with many to many relationship with the 2 objects